# How do I use jQuery to insert an li between two other li's when they contain siblings?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add a list item (Your Information) between two other list items (FirstName and Email), but have been unsuccessful because the two list items contain siblings. Thanks for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('<li>Your Information</li>').insertAfter('#FirstName');

});
</script>

<form class="lpeRegForm"><ul class='mktLblLeft'>
<li  class='Field' >
<label>First Name:</label>
<span class='Input'>
<input class='FormText' name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type='text' value=""    maxlength='255' tabIndex='1' />
<span class='FormMsg'></span>
</span>
</li>
<li  class='Field' >
<label>Email Address:</label>
<span class='Input'>
<input class='FormText' name="Email" id="Email" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='2' />
<span class='FormMsg'></span>
</span>
</li>  
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems to be working great when i test it http://jsfiddle.net/muSrP/ What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Simon - When you look at the source code you will see that it adds <li>Your Information</li> between the span tags vs. the actual list items.

Comment: Why don't you specify .insertAfter('.Field1') in this case?

Comment: @Simon Good point..  Actually, each <li> has the same class name (my bad).  I went ahead and made the change in the example now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert it after the `li` that `#FirstName` is inside of.  E.g.,

```
$('<li>Your Information</li>').insertAfter($('#FirstName').closest('li'));
```

---

Edit: this alternative syntax is arguably cleaner:

```
$('#FirstName').closest('li').after('<li>Your Information</li>');
```

Comment: I tried your solution but can seem to get it to work.  You can see here:  http://jsfiddle.net/TMzXE/

Comment: You should select a version of jQuery under `Choose Framework`. The default (what you have here), is MooTools.